# can i get location with GPS while my application is closed?

Tags: iphone, ios, objective-c, gps, location

I've seen application on iphone called "moves"

the gps is running on background while the application is totaly closed and not working in the background.

how can i get the location of the user and send it to the application while it is closed and not working on background? how could this possible?

what is the function to do that?

thanks

Comment: I am pretty certain that you cannot do that: if your could, that would be a rather serious privacy concern.

Comment: I think you have your terms mixed. There is a **HUGE** difference between an app running in the background and an app being closed. Apps can't do anything while they're closed except trigger push notifications.

Answer (score 1):

It is possible to get the location while the phone is running in the background (The Google Maps app does this), however running a background thread is a privilege that you must justify to Apple in their review process.

Here is some [documentation by Apple](http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#documentation/iphone/conceptual/iphoneosprogrammingguide/ManagingYourApplicationsFlow/ManagingYourApplicationsFlow.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40007072-CH4-SW3) for guidelines for running in the background

Comment: I think he's not referring to running in the background. He's referring to running when the app is already terminated.

Comment: Either way, you can register to receive location updates. Here is another link to the [Apple docs](http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#documentation/UserExperience/Conceptual/LocationAwarenessPG/CoreLocation/CoreLocation.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40009497-CH2-SW10) regarding location updates when your app isn't even backgrounded.

Comment: this is not the question, evry app can run in the background and get locations. its not a special privilege. its a simple configuration setting.

Answer (score 0):

You register for the significant-change location service.

According to the [Apple docs](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/iPhone/Conceptual/iPhoneOSProgrammingGuide/BackgroundExecution/BackgroundExecution.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40007072-CH4-SW25):

> If the app starts this service and is then terminated, the system relaunches the app automatically when a new location becomes available.

Answer (score -2):

This is not possible for an App on a non jailbraked iphone. Check again what you really have seen.
Apps can run in the background and get locations. But an app which is closed, can not do anything, since it is not running.
Maybe you have sawn the GPS Arrow in the status bar, staying active. But this disappears after some seconds, as long as no other application uses GPS.